# Check duplicate jobs having same parameters in Laravel

Tags: laravel, redis, queue, jobs

I have a cron which triggers thousands of crons on a single execution. So till the jobs are executing, I have some other files, from where the same job might be called with same parameter. I want to prevent that.

So basically, Before triggering a queue, system should check whether the same job with same parameter exists or not on queue. How can i achieve that?

Thank you.

Comment: You can try to make the commands [isolateable](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/artisan#isolatable-commands) but that only works if most of the jobs are different commands

Comment: I am not sure. The only idea  I got is to create a unique identifier and cache it. before running jobs, check the value, if new run + cache. Else skip

Comment: before triggering the queue i want to check jobs in pending state not all jobs. I think for this caching might not work and it seems little complex also. is there any other way though ?

Answer (score 0):

As from the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/queues#unique-jobs):

> Sometimes, you may want to ensure that only one instance of a specific
> job is on the queue at any point in time. You may do so by
> implementing the ShouldBeUnique interface on your job class.

And more specifically:

> In certain cases, you may want to define a specific "key" that makes
> the job unique or you may want to specify a timeout beyond which the
> job no longer stays unique. To accomplish this, you may define
> uniqueId and uniqueFor properties or methods on your job class:

```
<?php
 
use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
 
class UpdateSearchIndex implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
    /**
     * The product instance.
     *
     * @var \App\Product
     */
    public $product;
 
    /**
     * The number of seconds after which the job's unique lock will be released.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $uniqueFor = 3600;
 
    /**
     * Get the unique ID for the job.
     */
    public function uniqueId(): string
    {
        return $this->product->id;
    }
}
```

So you just have to define how to determine your specific job's uniqueness and youre good to go.